# Trying to create a function to validate password without using re or main(), and will return true or false

Tags: python

```
def isValidPassword(pw):  
    SpecialSymbol = ["@", "#", "$", " ", "&", "%"]
    val = True   
    
    if len(pw) < 10:
        print("enter at least 10 characters")
        val = False
        
    if not any(char.isdigit(3) for char in pw):
        print("enter at least 3 digit numbers")
        val = False
        
    if not any(char.isupper() for char in pw):
        print("enter at least 1 uppercase letter")
        val = False
        
    if not any(char.islower() for char in pw):
        print("enter at least 1 lowercase letter")
        val = False
        
    if not any(char in SpecialSymbol for char in pw):
        print("enter at least 1 special character")
        val = False
    if val:    
        return val
        
    if (isValidPassword(pw)):
        print(True)    
    else:
        print(False)       
print(isValidPassword("1234rewq"))
```

it's returning [TypeError: str.isdigit() takes no arguments (1 given)], and im not sure why
sorry just started learning, was referencing some of the materials i could find but, dont really know what im doing

Comment: ```.isdigit()``` returns True or False according to the condition. What do you think ```char.isdigit(3)```

Comment: change the isdigit(), it is not correct, you can use something like `sum(char.isdigit() for char in pw) == 3`

Comment: besides the problem with `isdigit()` not being correct, the condition in `if val: return val`  is incorrect. You want to always `return val`, not only if it's True.

Comment: also you are calling `isValidPassword(pw)` from within the function `isValidPassword` which will probably cause a `RecursionError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sum` on function `isdigit()` instead of `any()`.

try this:

```
def isValidPassword(pw):  
    SpecialSymbol = ["@", "#", "$", " ", "&", "%"]
    val = True   
    
    if len(pw) < 10:
        print("enter at least 10 characters")
        val = False
        
    if sum(char.isdigit() for char in pw) < 3:
        print("enter at least 3 digit numbers")
        val = False
        
    if not any(char.isupper() for char in pw):
        print("enter at least 1 uppercase letter")
        val = False
        
    if not any(char.islower() for char in pw):
        print("enter at least 1 lowercase letter")
        val = False
        
    if not any(char in SpecialSymbol for char in pw):
        print("enter at least 1 special character")
        val = False
    if val:    
        return val
        
if (isValidPassword("1234rewq")):
    print(True)    
else:
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like what the returned error is trying to tell you, the `isdigit()` method doesn't take any argument. The correct way to use it is just `char.isdigit()`, and the method will check if your '***char***' is a digit or not and return `True` if it is else `False`. But in your case, you are supplying an integer 3 as argument to the method which shouldn't need to.

You can try what @user1740577 suggested.